# React: Dropdown component shown once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

I have a drop down component that looks like this:

```
 {...}
        this.state = {
            isVisible: false
        }
    }

    toggleDisplay() {
        this.setState({isVisible: !this.state.isVisible});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.toggleDisplay()}>click</button>
                {this.state.isVisible ? <MenuElements toggleDisplay={this.toggleDisplay} /> : '' }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

"MenuElements" is just a ul that has a li. On another page i am using this component multiple times, so whenever i click on the button, "MenuElements" is shown for each click. The problem is that i want only one component to be displayed. So if a MenuElements component is already displayed, if i click on another button, it closes the previous component, and opens the second one.

How could this be implemented in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Track the state *globally* (using something like redux, perhaps), and if there's one open already, close that one before opening another.

Answer (score 0):

You will somehow need to have a single state that defines which MenuItem is displayed. You could go with a global state with something like Redux, but if you are trying to build a reusable component, I guess it'd be best to wrap all of the MenuItem components in a parent component and keep a state there. That, I think, is the React way of doing it. Read this for an idea of how to design components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html.

BTW, I think there is an error in the Button onClick handler. It should be:

```
<button onClick={this.toggleDisplay.bind(this)}> // or bind it somewhere else
```

Also, the correct way to change state based on previous state is [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

```
// Correct
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
}));

// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd say this is du to the context of your callbacks. Have you tried forcing the context ?

```
<div>
    <button onClick={this.toggleDisplay.bind(this)}>
        click
    </button>
{this.state.isVisible ? 
    <MenuElements toggleDisplay={this.toggleDisplay.bind(this)} /> 
: '' }
</div>
```

Comment: I have binded the method in the constructor.